# Both asynchronus and synchronus function calls in the same node.js programme

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

In the following nodejs programme, with input.txt having just a string "abc" in it.

```
var fs = require("fs");
// Asynchronous read
fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
return console.error(err);
}
 console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
});

// Synchronous read

var data = fs.readFileSync('input.txt');
console.log("Synchronous read: " + data.toString());
console.log("Program Ended");
```

The out put is

```
Synchronous read: abc
Program Ended
Asynchronous read: abc
```

now, the question is , when the program starts getting executed, it first sees the asynchronous readfile call and runs the process of 'reading input.txt' in background, then the server sees the synchronous read call and again start reading the input.txt. But as the asynchronous call has first started the reading, by the time  the synchronous function completes reading the .txt, call back of of asynchronous function would have been passed to the events loop and should have been executed first..

so the first line out put should be

```
Asynchronous read: abc
```

where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as the asynchronous call has first started the reading, by the time the synchronous function completes reading the .txt, call back of of asynchronous function would have been passed to the **events loop and should have been executed first**..

The emphasized area is where the mis-understanding happens. The callback is passed to the callback queue, not the event loop. The event loop will not loop until after the callstack is empty, which can't happen until the synchronous action is complete.

Once the callstack is empty, the event loop will run, pop one callback off the callback queue, and execute it. That is why the asynchronous callback happens after the synchronous action and not before.

The callback **cannot** be executed while a synchronous action is being executed because while a synchronous action is being executed, the event loop is not looping.

No other javascript can be executed while a synchronous action is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

I think the program is following the next behaviour.

1.- Start reading the file asynchronous.

2.- **Immediately** start reading synchronous the same file (blocking the call stack).

3.-  While the the synchronous reading is executing, your asynchronous function ends and put the callback on the callback queue,  to be executed once the call stack is free.

4.- Once the synchronous function  and the console.log statement ends (the call stack is not blocked or busy anymore), so, the event loop moves the callback on the queue to the call stack and  the asynchronous callback is executed.

I'm not 100% sure about that, but i'm basing on this explanation and i think makes sense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ